# Remove plot axis values

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I was just wondering if there is a way to get rid of axis values, either the x-axis or y-axis respectively, in an r-plot graph.

I know that `axes = false` will get rid of the entire axis, but I would only like to get rid of the numbering.

Answer (score 227):

Remove numbering on x-axis or y-axis:

```
plot(1:10, xaxt='n')
plot(1:10, yaxt='n')
```

If you want to remove the labels as well:

```
plot(1:10, xaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
plot(1:10, yaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
```

Comment: but keep in mind that these remove the entire axis... there will be nothing there unless you use a bty setting that puts lines where your axes are.  The default is bty = 'o' and so normally there will be a box around the plot where axes would be.  But with a bty = 'n' there would just be points floating in space.

Comment: next answer by @RichieCotton is better

Answer (score 70):

Using base graphics, the standard way to do this is to use axes=FALSE, then create your own axes using Axis (or axis).  For example,

```
x <- 1:20
y <- runif(20)
plot(x, y, axes=FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE)
Axis(side=1, labels=FALSE)
Axis(side=2, labels=FALSE)
```

The lattice equivalent is

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(y ~ x, scales=list(alternating=0))
```

Comment: Plus one for the lattice explanation!

Answer (score 23):

@Richie Cotton has a pretty good answer above.  I can only add that this [page](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html) provides some examples.  Try the following:

```
x <- 1:20
y <- runif(20)
plot(x,y,xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = x, labels = FALSE, tck = -0.01)
```

Answer (score 11):

you can also put labels inside plot:

```
plot(spline(sub$day, sub$counts), type ='l', labels = FALSE)
```

you'll get a warning. i think this is because labels is actually a parameter that's being passed down to a subroutine that plot runs (axes?). the warning will pop up because it wasn't directly a parameter of the plot function.

Answer (score 1):

Change the axis_colour to match the background and if you are modifying the background dynamically you will need to update the axis_colour simultaneously.
* The shared picture shows the graph/plot example using mock data ()

```
### Main Plotting Function ###
plotXY <- function(time, value){

    ### Plot Style Settings ###

    ### default bg is white, set it the same as the axis-colour 
    background <- "white"

    ### default col.axis is black, set it the same as the background to match
    axis_colour <- "white"

    plot_title <- "Graph it!"
    xlabel <- "Time"
    ylabel <- "Value"
    label_colour <- "black"
    label_scale <- 2
    axis_scale <- 2
    symbol_scale <- 2
    title_scale <- 2
    subtitle_scale <- 2
    # point style 16 is a black dot
    point <- 16 
    # p - points, l - line, b - both
    plot_type <- "b"

    plot(time, value, main=plot_title, cex=symbol_scale, cex.lab=label_scale, cex.axis=axis_scale, cex.main=title_scale, cex.sub=subtitle_scale, xlab=xlabel, ylab=ylabel, col.lab=label_colour, col.axis=axis_colour, bg=background, pch=point, type=plot_type)
}

plotXY(time, value)
```

[image]