# add local image file in R presentation

Tags: r, markdown, local, imaging, presentation

I'm trying to include one imaging file (`.png`) using R markdown for R presentation.
I followed the suggestion from: [How to import local image using knitr for markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517020/how-to-import-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown)
but by using `![title](my.png)`, I get this error:

> Error: unexpected '[' in "!["

The `my.png` file is in current path. I also tried using absolute path but got the same error message.

Putting above inside the r chuck failed too.

I also tried

````
```{r,fig.width=350, fig.height=250,echo=FALSE}
library(png)
library(grid)
appimg <- readPNG('my.png')
grid.raster(appimg)
```
````

but failed too!

I am working on windows 7 R studio 0.98.1102 and R 3.2.1 .

Comment: Have you tried using the HTML syntax as mentioned in the link you provided?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! using HTML syntax got similar error message

Comment: you don't need to quote your image name.

Comment: thank you but I tried quoted or not  both failed.

Answer (score 20):

After a huge mount of Google search. I finanlly figure out what is the problem.

The key is that HTML cannot refer local file for security reason. Except that it is a local HTML file, then it can refer local file in the same file directory.

And R presentation is actually a HTML file like a webpage.

So, just put your image file the same directory with the HTML file, things will work. At least it worked for me.

Just use

`![some caption](img_file_name.png)`

Comment: How does one scale and center image added this way to r presentation?

Answer (score 6):

Removing the quotes actually worked for me and note that one better doesn't keep any spaces while naming the image as in use,

```
![title](my_image.png)
```

Using quotes or having spaces(when renamed) hasn't worked for me in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The 'imager' package makes this pretty easy:

```
library(imager)
myimg <- load.image("<pathto>/file.png")
plot(myimg)
```

Comment: Thanks, how could we remove x and y axis from plot in this package?

Comment: it's the regular base r `plot()` command so `plot(myimg, axes=FALSE)` would work as usual. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154242/remove-plot-axis-values

Answer (score 3):

If your output format is : slidy_presentation
You can use html code:

`<img src="/Users/name/folder/xyz.png";>`

Further, if you wish to align and adjust the image to a specific side (say right of your final output and specify a size) you can use something like -

`<img src="/Users/name/folder/xyz.png"; style="max-width:280px;float:right;">`