# Hide x and y axis from the plot loaded with imager package

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I try to code below to insert and display an image in the presentation file with rmarkdown:

```
library(imager)
img <- load.image('https://makeshop-multi-images.akamaized.net/figmaster1/shopimages/98/82/1_000000018298.jpg')
plot(img, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
```

Out:

[image]

My question is how could I remove x and y axis from the figure? which means I hope to remove the contents in the grey rectangles.

I've added `xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n"` inside `plot()`, it seems not working out.

**References:**

[Remove plot axis values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154242/remove-plot-axis-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
plot(img, axes=FALSE)
```

[image]

Check the documentation at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/imager/versions/0.42.13/topics/plot.cimg